# the difference between coscos2dx xna and cocos2dx for wp8

Tags: cocos2d-x

I was confused by the information on http://www.cocos2d-x.org/

What is the difference between cocos2dx xna and cocos2dx for wp8?

It looks like cocos2dx xna only support c# programming,

cocos2dx for wp8 support c++ and only support wp8

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell:
cocos2dx xna: 
supports WP7 & WP8, 
it's a port written in C# (because at the time WP7 didn't support native languages)

cocos2dx for wp8: 
Support WP8
It's written in C++ (it uses DirectX instead of OpenGL)